# How can I find out if the channels in my area is covered in the EPG in MediaCenter

Tags: windows-media-center

Where can you find out, if your area / cable provider is covered in the electronic program guide in Media Center?

I don't have a tuner and I want to know if I will get solid EPG-coverage before I buy one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the best I could find:

http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/mediacenter/getstarted/guide.mspx

*Iceland is not on their list of supported countries for EPG.*